# Passport authenticate, need basic explanation

Tags: node.js, authentication, passport.js, passport-local

Can someone explain what is and why do we include (req, res, next), at the end of the passport.authenticate, all I've seen so far in tutorials is that we need it because we want it to fire off immediately, but I don't really understand it.

Here is the code:

```
router.post('/login', (req, res, next) => { <br>
    passport.authenticate('local', { <br>
        successRedirect: '/songs/list', <br>
        failureRedirect: '/users/login', <br>
        failureFlash: true <br> 
    })(req, res, next);                  <---- *This line*
```

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring a function and calling it immediately..You do this so you can access the `req` object inside the `passport.authenticate`.

So if you need to access the request object inside the `passport` you need a custom callback.Your code seems not to use the `req` object, so you simple use

```
app.post("/protected",passport.authenticate("local",{
        successRedirect:"/user",
        failureRedirect:"/login"
    }),function(req,res){
});
```

And if you application need access to req object then :

```
app.get('/protected', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, profile) {
    if (err) { return next(err) }
    if (!user) { return res.redirect('/signin') }
    res.redirect('/account');
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

More info @ https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/1